# How to store every value after I click on an operator (+ - ..) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator, dom-events, addeventlistener, new-operator

I'm fairly new to Javascript. Started doing the odin project; now doing the calculator project. So I'm stuck at the storing values after pressing one operator.

```
    numberButtons.forEach(function(numberButton){
    numberButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
        displayCurrent.textContent+=numberButton.value;
        currentValue=parseInt(displayCurrent.innerText);
    })
})

operatorButtons.forEach(function(operatorButton){
    operatorButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        let operator=this.value;
        displayPrevious.textContent= displayCurrent.textContent+this.value;
        displayCurrent.textContent="";
        finalSum=operate(operator,currentValue,currentValue);
        currentValue=0;     


    })
})
```

Every time when I click on a number button it is displayed on the current display and the value is saved in current value.

Now when pressing a operator button I want to move the previous value in a different display plus with the operator that is pressed. So now how can I store the next values on every operator press and compute the result. For example I press <kbd>3</kbd> then the current display shows `3` press <kbd>+</kbd> current display nothing displays previous `3+` current value `3`, press <kbd>5</kbd> it should be current display `5` if I press <kbd>+</kbd> again the current display should be empty while the previous display should either show `8` or `5+3` until I press equal.

Sorry for the long post I'm new and eager to learn Javascript. I hope I can make it :).

Comment: Welcome and congrats on your well-elaborated question (better longer than missing important details). Your question would be even better and faster to read, if you __improve formatting__: see [Help: Formatting with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Maybe you can even post a _complete_ [example] using __Stack Snippets__ :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your second code block you would need to know what the *previous* operator was (appearing in the `displayPrevious` element), and use that for calling `operate()`. The operator that corresponds to the button that is being clicked, cannot be used for a calculation yet, as you don't have the second operand for it yet. So that operator should be saved in a variable for later use.

```
operatorButtons.forEach(function (operatorButton) {
    operatorButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (operator) { // Is there already a pending operator?
            finalSum = operate(operator, finalSum, currentValue);
        } else { // first time
            finalSum = currentValue;
        }
        displayCurrent.textContent = "";
        operator = this.value; // remember the new operator
        if (operator === "=") operator = ""; // this is not really an operator
        displayPrevious.textContent = finalSum + operator;
    });
});
```

The below snippet uses the above code with a minimalistic calculator. This only addresses your question, but does not deal with division, decimals, operator precedence, clearing the input, ...

```js
let buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll("#divButtons input[type=button]")];
let numberButtons = buttons.filter(button => !isNaN("0"+button.value));
let operatorButtons = buttons.filter(button => isNaN("0"+button.value));
let displayCurrent = document.querySelector("#current");
let displayPrevious = document.querySelector("#previous");
let currentValue = 0;
let finalSum = 0;
let operator = "";

function operate(operator, a, b) {
    switch (operator) {
        case "+": return a+b;
        case "−": return a-b;
        case "×": return a*b;
    }
}

numberButtons.forEach(function (numberButton){
    numberButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        displayCurrent.textContent += this.value;
        currentValue = +displayCurrent.textContent;
    });
})

operatorButtons.forEach(function (operatorButton) {
    operatorButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (operator) { // Is there already a pending operator?
            finalSum = operate(operator, finalSum, currentValue);
        } else { // first time
            finalSum = currentValue;
        }
        displayCurrent.textContent = "";
        operator = this.value; // remember the new operator
        if (operator === "=") operator = ""; // this is not really an operator
        displayPrevious.textContent = finalSum + operator;
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=button] { width: 100%; }
td[colspan="4"] { 
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: right;
}
td[colspan="4"]:after {
    content: '.';
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table id="divButtons">
    <tr><td colspan="4" id="previous"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4" id="current"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" value="7"></td><td><input type="button" value="8"></td><td><input type="button" value="9"></td><td><input type="button" value="+"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" value="4"></td><td><input type="button" value="5"></td><td><input type="button" value="6"></td><td><input type="button" value="−"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" value="1"></td><td><input type="button" value="2"></td><td><input type="button" value="3"></td><td><input type="button" value="×"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="button" value="0"></td><td><input type="button" value="="></td></tr>
</table>
```